# eclipse debugger: enter a method without entering nested methods

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

If I have code like the following:

```
execute(getA(), getB(), getC(), getD(), getE());
```

Is it possible to step directly into `execute()` without first stepping in and out each of the other methods?  I know I could set a breakpoint into the entry of `execute()`, but that method gets called in a ton of different places throughout my code and I don't want to sort through all the calls.  I also haven't really be able to come up with a condition to use on the entry breakpoint, because the method is called on the same object many times, but it's only one specific call that I'm interested in.

Comment: I've never seen a solution to this besides a break point inside `execute` which can be annoying, agreed, especially in a multithreaded environment. Only other thing you could really do is rewrite the method to store `getA()` etc. results into variables which you pass in directly

Comment: I think there's a "Run to Line" option on the RMB which you could use to run the currently suspended thread forward to that point. Does that do what you want it to do?

Answer (score 4):

You can use **Step Into Selection** for that. While stopped at a breakpoint, place the cursor on the method call that you *do * want to step into (in your example, that would be on `execute`). right-click, and choose **Step Into Selection**. That will step directly into whatever is "selected" (i.e., the method where the cursor is).

The default keyboard shortcut for **Step Into Selection** is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> on Windows (probably <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> on Mac).

Comment: I think that's as close as you get. Let me add, however, that using `Step Filtering` (found under `Preferences -> Java -> Debug` can also avoid **some** of the inconvinience. Especially, `Filter simple getters` can be useful when parameters are just retrieved by using getters. Admittedly, in many cases the method calls might do some work and will be part of your domain model you don't want to filter out.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you can change the source code, the nasty verbose way would be to split onto multiple lines...

```
 Object a = getA();
 Object b = getB();
 //...etc...

 execute(a, b, ...);
```

Now you put a breakpoint on the call to execute in this position and step in, it will go directly into execute.

Comment: I can change the code, but it's kind of a pain.  takes about 20 minutes to compile, and another 10 to deploy.  That's why I was hoping there was a direct way to step.

Comment: @ewok What JonK said then

Answer (score 0):

With the cursor inside the line you wish to stop at, right click and select "Run to Line" (or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, or whatever you may have changed the binding to). This will cause the suspended thread that you have selected in the Debug view to continue executing up to that line, and then stop. This should allow to you bypass the need to constantly step in/out and avoids the use of a full breakpoint.

A caveat though: when using Run to Line the debugger cannot know if the execution actually *will* hit the line you requested - so if it doesn't actually stop, it didn't execute the line you asked it to stop at.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be what the question is asking for. I understood the question to mean that the debugger is *already* at the `execute(getA(), getB()...)` line and the asker wants to step directly into `execute()` but not into `getA()`, `getB()`, etc.

Comment: @E-Riz So you put the cursor on the first line of `execute` and hit Run to Line.